# Test source directory Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I have a multi-module Maven3 project and I want to trigger JUnit testing. The current structure of the project is the following:

```
-- plugin
    |-- src
    |   |-- [package]
    |   |   -- [source code]
    |   |       
    |-- src-test
    |   |-- [package]
    |   |   -- [unit tests]
    |   |
    |   -- resources
```

If I move the `src-test` folder in the `src` folder the tests are working just fine. But I want to avoid changing the structure of the project.

I've already tried with `<testSourceDirectory>` tag in the pom but it didn't worked.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>yyyy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

  <build>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src-test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
        <configuration>

          <includes>
              <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <useUIHarness>false</useUIHarness>
          <providerHint>junit4</providerHint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Is there any solution?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should put your test code in a separate plug-in. See e. g. this [Tycho tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#executing-plug-in-unit-tests-with-tycho).

Comment: I'm trying to run JUnit test, not integration test. For integration test I use as voggella suggest separate plug-ins.

Comment: In general JUnit tests should be put in a separate plug-in to not pollute the dependencies. In Eclipse plug-ins are OSGi bundles and instead of a flat classpath dependencies are specified in the `MANIFEST.MF` file. Tycho resolves dependencies via p2 which differs from building plain Java application with Maven without Tycho.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but changing the structure of the project is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you show how you specified the JUnit dependency? In `MANIFEST.MF` as `Require-Bundle`?

Comment: in MANIFEST.MF I have a bundle in another plugin which is full of necessary libs. The issue is not the dependency of the JUnit, but the compiling of the unit tests when the folder structure is as I describe it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to this. I've added the src-test folder to the build.properties of the plugin.